# Cannot enable Ad Block plus for Galaxy S5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, adblock-plus

I am trying to use Ad Block Plus for my Samsung Galaxy S5.

I recently upgraded from a Galaxy S3 on which ABP worked flawlessly.  To install and configure it on my Galaxy S3 I used this guide

https://adblockplus.org/en/android-config-samsung-galaxy-s3

I have downloaded the app successfully but for whatever reason it does not appear to block ads when I configure it similarly

Comment: Is your device rooted? Most of these need root to work. If you are rooted try AdFree android from Big Tin Can. It works on the S5 perfectly (rooted)

Comment: Is there any kind of error message when downloading/applying hosts file?